# $ sudo su root

Tags: linux, unix, sudo

**下記は、どういう意味ですか？**

> $ sudo su root

・sudoなのにsu？
・わざわざroot指定している理由は？
・「sudo -s」と何が違うのでしょうか？

**環境**
・CentOS7

[man sudo](https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/sudo/man8/sudo.8.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`su`コマンドは**切り替え先**ユーザのパスワードを入力する必要がありますが、`sudo`は**切り替え元/実行ユーザ**のパスワードを入力すればコマンドを実行できます。

`/etc/sudoers`での許可次第ですが、質問の例だとrootのパスワードを直接入力せずにroot権限を取得するための実行方法、ということではないでしょうか。

Comment: `root` ユーザーが `su` する場合には `su` 先ユーザのパスワード入力する必要が無いと書いてあるともっとわかりやくなると思いました。

Answer (score 3):

> ・sudoなのにsu？
>   ・「sudo -s」と何が違うのでしょうか？

`sudo -s`の場合はホームディレクトリが元ユーザーのホームディレクトリになります。それによって、.bashrcなども元のユーザーのものが適用されます。

`sudo su`や`sudo su root`の場合は、ホームディレクトリが/rootになります。それによって、.bashrcはrootのものが適用されます。

> ・わざわざroot指定している理由は？

これは私にもわかりません。

Answer (score 1):

> ・「sudo -s」と何が違うのでしょうか？

CentOS では `always_set_home` が有効なので `sudo -s` と同じ効果になると思います。

Comment: 「always_set_home」、こんな設定項目もあるのですね。初めて知りました。参考になりました